# XML parsing on Android get multiple lines

Tags: android, xml, parsing, rss

Hello i'm trying to parse an RSS feed from a website and display it on my android application , the problem is that i get weird data. What i mean is that i get multiple lines of the same  of the RSS.

The RSS feed

```
    rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Recent Seismicity in Greece</title>
<link>
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/maps/recent.html
</link>
<description>Real-Time seismicity</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 06:44:01 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 06:44:01 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<webMaster>vkapetan@geol.uoa.gr (Vasilis Kapetanidis)</webMaster>
<item>
<title>M 2.7, 03/06 - 05:43:06 , 65.7 km SW of Rethimnon</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktzh&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktzh&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktvz&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
134.4 km SSE of Iraklion<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 04:02:39 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.17N <br> Longitude: 25.58E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 2.7
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 04:05:33</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktvz&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 1.2, 03/06 - 03:34:54 , 22.2 km N of Aegion</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktvb&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
22.2 km N of Aegion<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 03:34:54 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 38.45N <br> Longitude: 22.06E <br> Depth: 14km <br> M 1.2
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 03:36:03</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktvb&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 2.2, 03/06 - 03:30:08 , 64.3 km SSW of Rethimnon</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktux&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
64.3 km SSW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 03:30:08 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.88N <br> Longitude: 24.09E <br> Depth: 22km <br> M 2.2
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 03:32:37</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktux&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 1.6, 03/06 - 03:11:00 , 35.5 km WNW of Preveza</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktug&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
35.5 km WNW of Preveza<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 03:11:00 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 39.10N <br> Longitude: 20.39E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 1.6
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 03:12:18</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktug&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 1.2, 03/06 - 02:06:55 , 28.6 km WNW of Amfissa</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktsd&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
28.6 km WNW of Amfissa<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 02:06:55 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 38.63N <br> Longitude: 22.07E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 1.2
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 02:08:12</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktsd&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 1.9, 03/06 - 02:00:30 , 33.7 km NNW of Kalamata</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktry&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
33.7 km NNW of Kalamata<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 02:00:30 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 37.32N <br> Longitude: 21.96E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 1.9
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 02:03:30</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktry&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 1.6, 03/06 - 01:46:45 , 6.5 km WSW of Argostoli</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktrm&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
6.5 km WSW of Argostoli<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 01:46:45 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 38.15N <br> Longitude: 20.41E <br> Depth: 5km <br> M 1.6
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 01:48:01</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktrm&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 1.3, 03/06 - 01:16:17 , 25.2 km SSW of Levadhia</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktqm&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
25.2 km SSW of Levadhia<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 01:16:17 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 38.23N <br> Longitude: 22.75E <br> Depth: 5km <br> M 1.3
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 01:17:24</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktqm&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 2.6, 03/06 - 01:04:31 , 65.8 km SSW of Karpathos</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktqc&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
65.8 km SSW of Karpathos<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 01:04:31 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 35.14N <br> Longitude: 26.81E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 2.6
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 01:06:20</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktqc&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
M 1.8, 03/06 - 00:54:25 , 31.9 km SE of Karpenision
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktpt&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
31.9 km SE of Karpenision<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 00:54:25 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 38.62N <br> Longitude: 22.02E <br> Depth: 5km <br> M 1.8
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 00:59:03</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktpt&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 1.4, 03/06 - 00:49:29 , 28.4 km NW of Amfissa</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktpp&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
28.4 km NW of Amfissa<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 00:49:29 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 38.67N <br> Longitude: 22.11E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 1.4
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 00:53:05</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktpp&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 3.4, 03/06 - 00:42:31 , 76.0 km SSW of Karpathos</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktpj&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
76.0 km SSW of Karpathos<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 00:42:31 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 35.01N <br> Longitude: 26.91E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 3.4
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 01:19:18</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktpj&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>M 1.9, 03/06 - 00:39:40 , 37.3 km WSW of Kithira</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktph&lng=en
]]>
</link>
<description>
37.3 km WSW of Kithira<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 00:39:40 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 36.08N <br> Longitude: 22.66E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 1.9
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 3 June 2015 00:42:40</pubDate>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://www.geophysics.geol.uoa.gr/stations/gmaps3/eventpage.php?scid=uoa2015ktph&lng=en
]]>
</guid>
</item>
```

My Parser

```
    package com.sarakinosproductions.bampis.gquakes;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Bampis on 2/6/2015.
 */
public class QuakeParser {

    public final String PARSER_TAG = "parser_msg";

    private ArrayList<QuakeData> qData;

    private String urlString = null;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;

    //Constructor gia na dosoume to url pou exei to rss
    public QuakeParser(String seismoiURL){
        this.urlString = seismoiURL;

        qData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        String text=null;

        //Temp strings
        String title = "";
        String description = "";
        String pubDate = "";

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name=myParser.getName();

                switch (event){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;

                     case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                          text = myParser.getText();
                         break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(name.equals("title")){
                            title = text;
                        }

                        else if(name.equals("description")){
                            description =text;
                        }

                        else if(name.equals("pubDate")){
                            pubDate = text;
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                        break;
                }
                //Logging the data
                Log.i("RSS ROW", "Title:" + title + "//" + "Description:" + description + "//" + "Published Date:" + pubDate);
                //Storing the data

                qData.add(new QuakeData(title,description,pubDate));


                event = myParser.next();
            }
            parsingComplete = false;
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<QuakeData> fetchXML() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();

                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null);

                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        return qData;
    }
}
```

A sample of my log

```
    6-03 09:43:24.162  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 05:43:06 , 65.7 km SW of Rethimnon//Description:Real-Time seismicity//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 06:43:01 GMT
06-03 09:43:24.162  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 05:43:06 , 65.7 km SW of Rethimnon//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.162  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 05:43:06 , 65.7 km SW of Rethimnon//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.162  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.163  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.163  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.163  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.163  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.163  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.163  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.163  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:65.7 km SW of Rethimnon<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 05:43:06 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.90N <br> Longitude: 24.02E <br> Depth: 11km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
06-03 09:43:24.163  25029-25065/? I/RSS ROW﹕ Title:M 2.7, 03/06 - 04:02:39 , 134.4 km SSE of Iraklion//Description:134.4 km SSE of Iraklion<br> Time: 03-Jun-2015 04:02:39 (UTC) <br> Latitude: 34.17N <br> Longitude: 25.58E <br> Depth: 10km <br> M 2.7//Published Date:Wed, 3 June 2015 05:44:52
```

Answer (score 0):

I've make progress and i've found a solution. The problem was that i haven't specified a flag for understanding when the parsing progress was in the Items that i've cared for. My new working approach is this time using AsyncTask .

Here is my new Parser

```
public class DataParser extends AsyncTask {

    public final String PARSER_LOG_TAG = "parser_msg";
    private String xmlUrl;
    private URL url;

    ArrayList<Quake> qData;

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> description;
    ArrayList<String> pubDate;

    public DataParser(String xmlUrl1) {
        qData = new ArrayList<>();
        this.xmlUrl = xmlUrl1;

        this.title = new ArrayList<>();
        this.pubDate = new ArrayList<>();
        this.description = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        try {
            //Boolean gia na vlepoume an eimaste mesa se item kai oxi sto channel
            boolean insideItem = false;

            //Dinoume to url pou exei to rss feed
            url = new URL(xmlUrl);

            //Dimiourgoume kai arxikopoioume ton XmlPullParser mas
            XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser parser = parserFactory.newPullParser();

            //Orizoume to input stream gia ton parser mas
            parser.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                    if (parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = true;
                    } else if (parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        if (insideItem)
                            title.add(parser.nextText()); //extract the title
                    } else if (parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                        if (insideItem)
                            description.add(parser.nextText()); //extract the description
                    } else if (parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                        if (insideItem)
                            pubDate.add(parser.nextText()); //extract the description
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = false;
                }

                eventType = parser.next(); //move to next element
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<title.size();i++){
            qData.add(new Quake(title.get(i),description.get(i),pubDate.get(i)));
        }
        return qData;
    }


    private InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();

            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            return inputStream;
        } catch (IOException ioE) {
            ioE.printStackTrace();
        }
    return inputStream;
}

    public ArrayList<Quake> data()
    {
        return qData;
    }

}
```